# Merge 2 tables and fetch data one by one

Tags: mysql, query, select

I have two tables: `product` & `offers`.

`products` has `(prod_id, category_id, prod_name, brand, price, status)`
`offers` has `(offer_id, prod_id, offer_type, discount_amt, validity)`

[image]
I want to display products on a page, 20 products at a time.

The problem that I want to display all the products from the `offers` table arranged by descending `offer_id` and then display products from the `products` table except those in the offers table within that 20 limit.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward.

```
SELECT * from products left join offers on prod_id=prod_id
ORDER BY offer_id DESC LIMIT 20;
```

See it here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dff49/3/0