# Merge MySQL tables without data repetition

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

My situation is this: I have several DIFFERENT tables in my MySQL database with the same name columns. Such tables can contain (or not) the same data.

What I need to do is a kind of "merge" between these tables, creating a new table that will contain only the data repeated once.

In other words, I want to check for duplicate records in multiple tables, leaving one with the records without repetition.

A example to clarify:
I have 2 tables (in fact I have 10 tables, but 2 works for the example) with the columns id, name and city like below

```
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| id | name                                                    | city                  |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| 6  | HOTEL PANAMBY GUARULHOS                                 | guarulhos             |
| 31 | PLAZA INN MASTER                                        | new york              |
| 40 | PLAZA INN AMERICAN LOFT SãO PAULO                       | sao paulo             |
| 41 | PLAZA INN PARIS                                         | paris                 |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

The id '41' of table 1 could be equal to id '80' of table 2, for example and so subsequently. My task is compare the tables and create a new one without repetition. Don't exist any FK between tables, they are isolated.

Until now, I discovered two approaches to deal with this.

1) Using SELECT UNION. Apparently is the best approach, but I couldn't see the correct joins and group by to use it, once I don't have FKs;

2) Using a Stored Procedure with cursors for two tables and compare row by row. I tried use this one, but SP it isn't my speciality, so i created a good one, but the tables has over 1000 rows each one and my SP always crashed the memory.

I found this question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24399/merge-2-tables-and-fetch-data-one-by-one), but is not my case, I want a new table without repetition. Other questions in this site with similar problem talk about SQL Server and don't work for me.

Currently, I'm doing the workaround with a PHP script, but I'd like to know for any MyQSL solutions, if any. 
I found some articles about Dataclean, but I don't know if this is the case and never work with this in MySQL.

I hope I was clear.

Comment: SELECT name, city FROM t1 
UNION 
SELECT name, city FROM t2; 
should do it for you if difference in ID is not important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear to me, if you want to keep records, which are duplicated, or you want only those records, which are in only one of the tables.

You can try:

```
-- create tables
create table tbl1
(
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    city VARCHAR(25)
);

create table tbl2 like tbl1;

-- insert data
insert into tbl1 values (1,'adam', 'eden'), (2, 'eva', 'eden');
insert into tbl2 values (3,'adam', 'eden'), (4, 'pedro', 'alexandria');
```

This will give you records with unique `name` column:

```
select * from (select * from tbl1 union select * from tbl2) as a group by name;
+------+-------+------------+
| id   | name  | city       |
+------+-------+------------+
|    1 | adam  | eden       |
|    2 | eva   | eden       |
|    4 | pedro | alexandria |
+------+-------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

*Note:* this will keep `id` from `tbl1`, if you want to keep `id` from `tbl2`, just switch order of tables in sql statement

And this will give you only those records, which are in one, or other table, but not in both

```
select * from (select * from tbl1 union select * from tbl2) as a group by name having count(*) = 1;
+------+-------+------------+
| id   | name  | city       |
+------+-------+------------+
|    2 | eva   | eden       |
|    4 | pedro | alexandria |
+------+-------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: This is exactly what I need. It's much more simple than I thought. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an insert statement for every table:

```
create table tbl1
(
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    city VARCHAR(25)
);
create table tbl2
(
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    city VARCHAR(25)
);
insert into tbl1 values (1,'adam', 'eden'), (2, 'eva', 'eden');
insert into tbl2 values (3,'adam', 'eden'), (4, 'pedro', 'alexandria');
create table tbl3 as select * from tbl1;    
insert into tbl3 (id, name, city)
 select id, name, city from tbl2 where (name, city) not in (select name, city from tbl3);
```

@Zbynek I took the same data as you. Hope you do not mind.

Answer (score 0):

Here's 2 approaches.

This approach assumes that the combination (name, city) needs to be unique:

```
INSERT INTO New
    ( SELECT name, city FROM tbl1 )
    UNION DISTINCT
    ( SELECT name, city FROM tbl2 )
    UNION DISTINCT
    ( SELECT name, city FROM tbl3 );
```

In this approach, your `New` table needs to have a `UNIQUE KEY` (or `PRIMARY KEY`) that contains all the columns that are needed to determine uniqueness.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO New  SELECT name, city FROM tbl1;
INSERT IGNORE INTO New  SELECT name, city FROM tbl2;
INSERT IGNORE INTO New  SELECT name, city FROM tbl3;
```